# HtmlUnit - how to click an input element?

Tags: java, htmlunit-driver

There is a submit button in a form:

```
<input type="submit" class="button" value="Enter" tabindex="104" title="title text" accesskey="s">
```

next I select and submit it by the way

```
HtmlElement submit = currentPage.getHtmlElementByAccessKey('s');
submit.click();
```

But that does not submit the form, I'm checking page as text and it's visible that form still does not submiteed, how can I make it?

Answer (score 0):

In simple cases (without javascript/ajax magic) you should do

```
resultPage = submit.click();
```